# Paywall partial content in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on a component, which receives its main content data from an **external api**.

The data is in the form of string with html content, so I am using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render content.

```
{ ....

content: "<div id="attachment_565754" class="wp-caption alignnone"> <img class="size-large wp-image-565754"...../>"

......
}

<div className="col col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"dangerouslySetInnerHTML {{__html: this.props.postDetails.content}}>
</div>
```

The requirement is to partially hide content, once the user has visited the site 5 times. For the time being I am using **localstorage** keep track of user visits, as the temporary solution for this part.

But how do I partially block the content, when all the content is coming from an external api.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you wouldn't even load it if you don't need it. Then, regardless of if you've loaded it or not, use some local variables to determine if it should render:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {};
}

componentDidMount() {
  const shouldLoad = this.shouldLoad(); // Would return true/false based on localStorage value

  if (shouldLoad) {
    someDataCall().then((data) => {
      this.setState({ data });
    });
  }
}

render() {
  const data = this.state.data;

  return (
    <div>
    {data &&
      <div
        className="col col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.postDetails.content}}>
      </div>
    }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Doing this, the div with data in it is only rendered if data has been loaded, and data will only load if your `localStorage` values say it should.

Comment: But I still want to show content say if  the user visited the site 6th time, but only partially. As you see in those journalism related sites, where they only show the first paragraph and then blur the rest out.

Comment: You want to split the content you're rendering with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and hide half of it? That would require some hacking outside the React because we have no control over the content after giving it to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: Though you could modify what is put into `data` when you get the response from the network call, though that would require you to parse HTML. Seems like you should have a way of telling the API what data you need.